# начальная страница fragment в drawer activity

Tags: java, android

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы при запуске приложения начальная страница была fragment.В mainactivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        try {
            readFile();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Если эту строчку поменять  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`на фрагмент, то ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого просто нужно вручную добавить начальный фрагмент в ваш контейнер в конце метода `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    // Вся ваша инициализация
    ...

    Fragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, firstFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: сделал так:`fragments1 firstFragment = new fragments1();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, firstFragment);
        transaction.commit();` но теперь этот фрагмент всегда на заднем плане

Comment: @Сашка А как вы добавляете другие фрагменты? Случайно не через `add`? Нужно через `replace`.

Comment: `fragments3 fragmentik =fragments3.newInstance("some1","some2");
            FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                    fragmentik,
                    fragmentik.getTag()
            ).commit();`  Через replace

Comment: Первый фрагмент добавляется в контейнер `R.id.container`, остальные в `R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment`. Это опечатка или на самом деле так? Нужно добавлять в один контейнер.

Comment: опечатка)разобрался спасибо)